# Undocumented error when trying to add a dataset to an RDLC report

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

[image]

When I am trying to add dataset in rdlc report of my existing project then then shows this error. I have rebuild all assemblies in this project but its not working.

Comment: I am facing this problem only in Visual 2010. In VS 2012 it working correctly.

Comment: It looks like you have a custom library WF_BO that is missing or there is an error with the reference.